# What is the proper regular expression to validate pakistani mobile number?

Tags: regex, validation, mobile, numbers

I want to validate pakistani mobile number in my php registration form. I need a regular expression that validate all the pakistani numbers (zong, ufone, telenore, jazz, warid) e.g `03337800766` or `+923124432876`

```
^((\+92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$
```

I used this code but its not working

```
if(!preg_match("/^((\+92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$/", $mobile)){
    echo "Mobile number is valid";
}
```

There is not any error but it show no effect our any number

Comment: `?` serves the same purpose as `{0,1}` and takes up way less space

Answer (score 1):

you made a mistake, try `^((\+92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$`
 The "+" need to be escaped

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format:

```
^((\+923|923|03)(([0-4]{1}[0-9]{1})|(55)|(64))[0-9]{7})$
```

If a user puts "0378 XXXXXXX", we know that this one number is not valid in Pakistan.
As a user puts "0300-0309/0310-0319/0320-0329/0330-0339/0340-0349/0355/0364", these are only valid phone numbers in Pakistan.

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as

```
**/^923\d{9}$|^03\d{9}$/**
```

This code will validate both type of numbers with 923 or with 03 if you need to validate +923 then use following code.

```
**/^+923\d{9}$|^923\d{9}$|^03\d{9}$/**
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression to validate the Pakistan Mobile number

> **^((+92|0092||92|0){1}(3)[0-9]{9})$|^(((+92|0092|92){1}((\s?)|(-?))(3)|(03))[0-9]{2}((\s?)|(-?))[0-9]{7})$**
>
> *Example:*
>
> 03457172848 Valid
>
> 0345-7172848 Valid
>
> 0345 7172848 Valid
>
> 345-7172848 NOT Valid
>
> -345-7172848 NOT Valid
>
> 034571-72848 NOT Valid
>
> 0-3457172848 NOT Valid
>
> +923457172848 Valid
>
> 00923457172848 Valid
>
> 923457172848 Valid
>
> 920457172848 NOT Valid
>
> 92-345-7172848 Valid
>
> 92 345 7172848 Valid
>
> 92-0345-7172848 NOT Valid
>
> (+92)3457172848 NOT Valid